# Add custom div as control to Google Maps API V2

Tags: google-maps, html, google-maps-api-2

I can seem to do this for V3 but cannot find any examples for V2

I want to embed the following DIV contents below, ideally keep within a function so that is is easily changed..

```
    function embedLogo() {
          return "<a href='http://website.net/?ref=19299'><img src='./images/seestuff.png' /></a>"; 
    }
```

I would like this in the bottom right and an example of it on v3 is at [http://www.planefinder.net](http://planefinder.net/?ref=stack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sorted it for me

http://googlemapsapi.martinpearman.co.uk/articles.php?cat_id=2